# Is anybody experiencing Apex CPU timeout exceptions after Summer 19 release upgrade

Tags: cpulimit, summer19

Just wanted to check if anybody else is experiencing this. Last friday everything was running perfectly. On saturday our instance was upgraded to Summer 19, and on monday we started seeing Apex CPU timeouts in some of our more heavy processes.

Before I start digging to heavily into potential changes on our side, I just wanted to check if anybody else had this too.

Comment: I am noticing that today in particular, one of our heavy orgs is getting more CPU limit exceptions than ever before.

Comment: Opened a case with Salesforce. Unit tests that have been running for years are suddenly failing due to Apex CPU Time Limits. Haven't heard anything back yet....

Comment: Hi and welcome to all new SFSE users. If you found this question via search and are also affected, please *do not add a "me too" answer*. You're welcome to comment if you have information to add, or write an answer if you can help solve the problem.

Comment: Has this also been raised on Trailblazer or Partner Community yet? My first attempt to search for it was not fruitful.

Comment: I have received initial feedback from support stating that this is known, but is actually a fix to cpu time not correctly adding up before. I am following up on this and will keep you posted.

Comment: Here is the "fix" that Summer 19 applied concerning CPU timeout that Ivar was referring to.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008q7VQAQ&title=apex-cpu-time-limit-is-not-enforced-if-an-apex-test-runs-in-synchronous-mode

Comment: This doesn't square with our experience as we're now experiencing CPU timeouts in PRODUCTION non-test code that didn't throw them before. The fix listed here says for unit tests only.

Comment: There is this one as well.

SObjectType.getDescribe() and SObjectField.getDescribe() increase Apex CPU consumption in API version 44+

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001RXBZQA4&title=sobjecttype-getdescribe-and-sobjectfield-getdescribe-increase-apex-cpu-consumption-in-api-version-44

Comment: To give all an update: This was indeed a problem following the Summer 19 release, which apparently now correctly counts/measures CPU time and enforces the limits more strictly. Salesforce has given us a temporary increase in allowance, but it is our responsibility to tackle and change our code to become compliant.

Answer (score 2):

There is a known issue from Summer '19 where DML operations are contributing towards the CPU limit. Even if there are no triggers on the sObject in question.

See Known Issue: [DML Insert operations consumes Apex CPU time](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000AT8oQAG&title=dml-insert-operations-consumes-apex-cpu-time)

That could certainly have a wide ranging impact across all transactions. If the transactions were already close to the limits this could have pushed it past the edge.